# How to check if the GPS is ON or OFF

Tags: xamarin.forms

I can get Latitude and Longitude using Xamarin.Essentials but is there any way to check the status of GPS for Xamarin forms. I have used the following code but didn't get any result:
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Comment: You should check the [Geolocator plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin), now included on the [Xamarin Essential package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

Comment: Wrong use of supportive words, which had changed the meaning of sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with [GeolocatorPlugin](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html) ,this plugin can help check whether GPS is ON or Off easily.

```
public bool IsLocationAvailable()
{
    if (!CrossGeolocator.IsSupported)
        return false;

    return CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationAvailable;
}
```

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin